# Core Data: refreshObject:mergeChanges: faulting with a "missing link"

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Let's say that I have the following entity-relationship model:

```
A <-->> B <-->> C <-->> D
```

A is my root object and I have it retained somewhere in my application.  I use an NSFetchRequest to grab a particular instance of C and all of it's underlying D objects, so B has not been registered with the context.  After I'm done with C, I want to clear that memory by saving and using refreshObject:mergeChanges: to turn it back into a fault, along with all of its D objects.  However, I'd like to leave my A object intact.

As all related entities will be turned back into a fault, will Core Data follow the graph back to my A object or will the lack of a registered B object in the context to link the two stop that?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the latter (no changes to A) but you can check this easily by overriding `willTurnIntoFault` in your managed object subclass:

```
- (void) willTurnIntoFault
{
    NSLog(@"%@ will turn into fault", self.name);
    [super willTurnIntoFault];
}
```